# Scrapy doesn't do any scraping after login on salesforce.com based site

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and have an issue logging in to a salesforce.com based site. I use the loginform package to populate scrapy's FromRequest. When run, it does a GET of the login page and a sucessful POST of the FormRequest login as expected. But then the spider stops, no page gets scraped.

```
[...]
2017-06-25 14:02:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://testdomain.secure.force.com/jSites_Home> (referer: None)
2017-06-25 14:02:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://login.salesforce.com/> (referer: https://testdomain.secure.force.com/jSites_Home)
2017-06-25 14:02:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[...]
```

The (slightly redacted) script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from loginform import fill_login_form
from harvest.items import HarvestItem


class TestSpider(Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['testdomain.secure.force.com', 'login.salesforce.com']
    login_url = 'https://testdomain.secure.force.com/jSites_Home'
    login_user = 'someuser'
    login_password = 'p4ssw0rd'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.login_url, self.parse_login)

    def parse_login(self, response):
        data, url, method = fill_login_form(response.url, response.body, self.login_user, self.login_password)
        return scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=dict(data), method=method, callback=self.get_assignments)

    def get_assignments(self, response):
        assignment_selector = response.xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/ul/li/a[@title="Assignments"]/@href')
        return Request(urljoin(response.url, assignment_selector.extract()), callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = HarvestItem()
        items['startdatum'] = response.xpath('(//*/table[@class="detailList"])[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/text()')\
            .extract()
        return items
```

When I check the body of the FormRequest, it looks like a legit POST to the page 'login.salesforce.com'. If I login manually, I notice several redirects. However, when I force a parse by adding a "callback='parse'" to the FormRequest, still nothing happens.

- Am I right in thinking the login went OK, looking at the 200 response?
- I don't see any redirects in the scrapy output. Could it be that scrapy doesn't handle the redirects properly, causing the script to not do any scraping?

Any ideas on getting the script to scrape the final redirected page after login?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't define a callback function in your `parse_login` `FormRequest`. So you would need something like `scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=dict(data), method=method, callback=self.parse_item)`

Comment: @Casper: Shouldn't it be sufficient to return a respons object in a CrawlSpider? As far as I understand it should then run a default parser...

Comment: for every request you do, you need to tell the spider what function to use. If you have 80 functions to extract data from different sort of pages, the spider won't know which one to use (unless you specify a callback). Did you try adding the callback? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Casper: If I add callback='parse' to parse_login, then I get an error.
`twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: <200 https://login.salesforce.com/>`

Comment: Please make sure to add `callback=self.parse_item` as you don't have a function called `parse` but the function you created is `parse_item`. And make sure you add `self.` before the function name as it won't be able to find the function otherwise.

Comment: @Casper: I've added a self.parse function (which in return calls parse_item). This causes a page to be scraped. But, it scrapes the page 'login.salesforce.com, not the final redirected page I get after a manual login. It seems the redirects don't take place after the login or the login silently fails.

Comment: You might want to test your request by performing it in scrapy shell and view the response. If you run into problems with logging in properly, I suggest to create a new question.